# calculate the median of intervals of a vector in R

Tags: r, probability, median, usage-statistics

I have the following challenge:
Let X be a V.A. discrete evenly distributed in the interval [1, 10]. Be Y
another V.A. each sample of Y is given by the median value of one
set of 10 X samples. Generate 10^6 Y samples.

I'm using R, with the following code:

```
x <- runif(10000000,1,10)
sample <- cut(x,breaks=10)
y = median(sample)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
 mosaic::median(~x|sample)
```

or in base R:

```
 tapply(x, sample, median)
```

Comment: I didn't know about that `mosaic::median`.  Thanks for sharing